# Does MinGW cross-compile IA64?

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling, itanium

I want to cross-compile Windows IA64 binaries in Linux platform.

Can MinGW be ported to do it?

Comment: Older _Visual Studio_ versions (e.g. 2010) are able to generate _IA64_ binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. MinGW produces 32-bit executables only. [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) supports 32 and 64-bit x86 binaries but not IA64

> #### Features
>
> - ...
> - **Supports 32-bit and 64-bit Windows i386/x64**
> - Supports Multilib toolchains
> - Supports bleeding edge gcc/binutils
>
> https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

There was a request to support Windows IA64 in GCC long time ago but I doubt it anyone would spend time supporting that architecture. Even Microsoft abandoned Itanium for years.

> > To the Team of GCC,
> >     Our Developing Team is looking for a 64-bit Compiler that would be
> >     able to Compiler 64-Bit Windows Applications for the IA-64 Architecture and
> >     possibly the x86-64 bit Architecture.
> >     I am Inquiring as to whether a IA-64 Windows Platform Version of GCC has
> >     yet been procured or if not when in the future a version might come across.
> >
> > https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-09/msg00346.html
>
> ---
>
> > There is no IA-64 windows support in gcc at this time.
> >     It will be available if and when someone contributes the code to the FSF.
> >     It is not possible to predict if or when this will happen.
> >
> > https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-09/msg00363.html

Forking mingw to support IA64 might be possible but would take a lot of effort. I think the easiest way is using LLVM because only a [backend](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html) for [translating IR to IA64 instructions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/llvm-ia64/) is needed